# Submit_tag confirm msg is not presenting the confirm msg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, tags, haml

I have a Ruby HAML site where I need to have the user confirm that they have reviewed Terms and Conditions.  I am using submit_tag to navigate from a cart screen to the checkout process and would like a confirmation msg on the Checkout (submit_tag)  I have = javascript_include_tag "Application" in my application erb file.

I have tried :confirm "I have reviewed the terms" and 
data: confirm("I have reviewed the terms") the first compiles the data: produces a syntax error. 
I also tried using onclick

``
.row.hidden-xs.hidden-sm.visible-md.visible-lg

.col-sm-12.button-hover{:style => "text-align:right;text-size:3em;padding-right:30px"}
  = submit_tag 'Checkout', :confirm => ("I have agreed to the Terms and Conditions"), :class => "btn btn-primary"

```
When I click Checkout it routes to the checkout page with no prompt or msg.
```

Comment: This is the proper syntax that resolved the issue:

   ` .col-sm-12.button-hover{:style => "text-align:right;text-size:3em;padding-right:30px"}
        
    = submit_tag 'Checkout', :class => "btn btn-primary", :data => {:confirm => "I have 
    agreed to the Terms and Conditions"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submit tag should look something like:
`<%= submit_tag "Checkout", class: "classes here", data: {confirm: "I have agreed to the Terms and Conditions"}%>`

I believe in haml it would just start with a =

You could do an onClick event that goes to a javascript function. You will need to pass the function the event parameter.

```
onClickFunction(event) { 
  event.preventDefault;
  // whatever else you want to do. Show a modal or ect.
}
```

The preventDefault stops the action from doing what it would normally do. This allows you to show a prompt or something else. At the end of doing everything you will need to finish by getting around the prevented action.

Some more stuff from the docs:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag

```
submit_tag "Save", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
# => <input name='commit' type='submit' value='Save' data-confirm="Are you sure?" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the explenation.  Your direction helped narrow my search criteria and I found the correct syntax

Comment: ```.col-sm-12.button-hover{:style => "text-align:right;text-size:3em;padding-right:30px"}
                  = submit_tag 'Checkout', :class => "btn btn-primary", :data => {:confirm => "I have agreed to the Terms and Conditions"} ```